# Tkinter GUI to ask to select a file - Tkinet, Numpy, Openpyxl, Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I working with openpyxl, pandas and numpy to modify an excel file. So far I have been just specifying which file I want to modify but I would like to use the tkinter GUI below to ask user to select the file which they want to modify. I cant seem to get it working. What am I doing wrong??

```
    import openpyxl
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
    
    
    #TKINTER GUI -----------------------------------------
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import filedialog
    
    def UploadAction(event=None):
        wb = filedialog.askopenwb()
        print('Selected:', filename)
    
    root = tk.Tk()
    button = tk.Button(root, text='select File', command=UploadAction)
    button.pack()
    root.geometry('150x150')
    
    root.mainloop()
    
    #TKINTER GUI -----------------------------------------
    
    # X = input(str("Enter File Name: "))
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("Test.xlsx")
    
    wb.create_sheet("Results")
    wb.create_sheet("my Pivot")
    wb.create_sheet("SQL Pivot")
    
    
    wb.active = 2
    Results = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Results')
    Results['A3'] = 'Weekly Average Spend'
    Results['A4'] = 'Cost Per Trip'
    Results['A5'] = 'Average Trips Per Week'
    Results['A6'] = 'Total Spend'
    
    
    #Results['B3'] = 
    #Results['B4'] = 
    #Results['B5'] = 
    #Results['B6'] = 
    
    df = pd.read_excel("Test.xlsx")
    MyPiv = pd.pivot_table(df, index = ['weeknum'], values = ['Total Actual Cost','TB ID'], aggfunc =('sum','count')) 
    
    print(MyPiv)
    
    sd = pd.read_excel("Test.xlsx","SQL")
    SqlPiv = pd.pivot_table(sd,index = ['Ship_Date_Year' , 'Ship_Date_Weeknum'], values ['Customer_Amt_Excl_Fuel'], aggfunc = ('sum'))
    
    print(SqlPiv)
                                
    
    wb.save("Test.xlsx")
```

Comment: Does it have to be tkinter. What about PyQt?

Comment: why cant it be in tkinter?

Comment: @ThePilotDude I am not familiar with that tool. but as long as it will solve the problem, im okay with it.

Comment: Why do you think it's not working? What does it do?

Comment: @BryanOakley GUI itself works, it asks me to select a file. But that is not connected to the openpyxl "wb" file. I want to be able to select the file & assign it to "wb"

Answer (score 0):

Running your code outputs a SyntaxError in line 51 (in the 2nd call to `pd.pivot_table`), you forgot an equals sign after `values`.